# How to construct a semi-computable set?

Tags: logic, set-theory, computability, decidability

How can I construct/define arbitrary semi-computable (but not computable) sets?

Recall that a set A is semi-computable if it is domain of a computable function f. Recall also that a set A is computable if and only if both A and the complement set (A<sup>c</sup>) are semi-computable.

In particular, I am looking for a semi-computable (but not computable) set A, such that A is a proper subset of E, where E is the set of even numbers. E = { 2x | x € N }

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Typically, writing down something that is not computable is challenging.  Most characterizations can't be explicit because those constructions lead to computable objects.  Can you describe the type of answer you're looking for?

Comment: Are you familiar with the set that is usually denoted as $\mathcal K$? It is the set of codes that represent a function that is not defined on that code, and is semi-computable and not computable. Then try its intersection with the set of even numbers.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I am taking a course in computability theory and saw this as an exercise in my book. This question comes after the set K is introduced, which is a set that is defined via diagonalization (so that it cannot be computable) . I am expecting the answer to this question to somehow manipulate K and E to create the wanted A set, but I might be wrong and the K set is not needed at all. If you would like any more context to help solve this problem, please let me know.

Comment: @drhab I am familiar with the said set, and your proposition sounds interesting because the intersection guarantees that I get a subset of E, but there is 1 problem remaining. How will I know that the intersection set is semi-computable (just like K)? I do not know of a theorem that states that any subset of a semi-computable set is also semi-computable.

Comment: See https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01770562/document

Comment: The way to do this is not with the intersection $K\cap E.$  What does work is $\{2x \mid x\in K\},$ where $K$ can actually be any set that is semi-computable but not computable.

Comment: @MitchellSpector your answer seems correct, at least I confirmed that the other answer is surely false, as interesecting with a semi-computable set does not mean the resulting set will be semi-computable.

Comment: Sorry for my misleading suggestion. It was just the first thought that came up in me. Without having examined it properly it was not okay to put it in a comment. I sinned against my own rules and apologize. Further I am glad to see that your question has been answered.

Comment: @SHCMostWanted You probably know this already, but in the interest of accuracy: The intersection *is* guaranteed to be semi-computable.  The problem that arises is that it might actually be computable (and the problem called for an example which was a non-computable set).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is provided by @Mitchell Spector in comments.

Pick any semi-computable, but not computable set $K$. Then, a new set can be defined as $\{ 2x \mid x \in K\}$.

Such a set is a proper subset of $E$ because it consists only of even numbers, and it cannot be computable (but it is semi-computable), because if it was computable, then $K$ would be computable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi_0,\phi_1,\phi_2,\ldots$ be an enumeration of all $n$-ary partial recursive functions.

It is well-known that the set $K=\{x\mid x\in dom\,\phi_x\}$ is semi-computable. Moreover, the set $K\cap E$ is semi-computable which you can easily check.

Add: Suppose $K\cap E$ is decidable. Then the complement must be semi-decidable. Otherwise, $K$ would be decidable. Now change the encoding $\phi_n$ of the partial recursive function by exchanging even and odd.

Comment: Can you briefly explain why $K\cap E$ has to be semi-computable? For all I know, the interesection of those might even be an empty set. I am missing a piece here.

Comment: But $K\cap E$ may be computable, depending on your initial enumeration of the partial recursive functions (or, equivalently, of Turing machines). For example, you can pick an enumeration which has $\phi_x$ being the empty function for all even $x.$

Comment: @MitchellSpector although I am still waiting for a reply from the author, I think this is not an issue as you are not picking an enumeration. Watch carefully how the set K is defined, you cannot "pick" anything, it iterates through a list domains of all partial recursive functions. There are infinitely many such functions.

Comment: @SHCMostWanted  That's not correct.  The set $K$ depends on the enumeration $\phi_0, \phi_1, \dots,$ which in turn depends on a computable enumeration of Turing machines (or whatever formalism you want to use for partial recursive functions).  There are many ways of doing this; look up "acceptable enumerations" if you want to read about this.  For some acceptable enumerations, the corresponding $K\cap E$ will be computable; for some acceptable enumerations, it won't be computable.

Comment: @SHCMostWanted I added a comment to the main question showing how the problem can actually be solved.  (I think the comment belongs there, rather than on this answer, since this answer is not correct.)